# git pull: update repo without changing the contents of a specific directory

Tags: git, git-pull

I want to update my local system repo with the remote one, but I do not want to touch the contents of one specific directory myDir.
Note that this directory was updated later in the master branch but I want to keep my old version of it.

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Are these changes you want to keep referenced by a particular commit, or are they uncommitted in the current branch?

Comment: they are uncommited in the current branch

Comment: Is your current branch master or another one? (If it is another one, you can safely commit them and then rebase if you want to refine your commit later.)

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is just `git fetch` and `git merge` wrapped into one.

If you just want to update your repo without merging, a simple `git fetch` will suffice.

Comment: Let me try and clarify: my local branch is older than the remote master branch. I want to merge all the changes from the remote master branch but would like to keep the old version of a certain directory. Ideally, I would use a pull command with an "ignore directory" flag.

Comment: Git does not allow for partial checkouts (as you might expect from systems such as SVN).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a pull from a remote to overwrite work you have not yet committed, use `stash` to save your work temporarily.  From your working directory:

1. `git stash` will take all your uncommitted changes an save them onto an external stack
2. You can now `git pull` and update your local repo with changes from the remote
3. Now use `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` to bring the changes you stashed back into the working directory after the `pull`

Another tip: You can stash multiple blocks of work and they all stack; use `git stash list` to see all the items you have currently stashed.

Comment: `git stash` is an unnecessary complication in this scenario, if I understand OP correctly.